# Querying infopath form library

Tags: sharepoint, moss, infopath

Is there a tool that allows querying (and aggregating data from) a library of infopath forms in MOSS? I can't use promoted fields, since some of the items I want to query are in repeating groups which (AFAIK) cannot be promoted. So I have to query the underlying XML.

I realize I can write custom code that iterates through the forms and perfoms a xpath query on each, I just wonder if there is an existing tool or functionality for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lists.asmx web service to retrieve the XML and work with it within reporting services or even within Excel.

Look at using XML as a data source in [SQL reporting services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129.aspx)

if you export the list to a spreadsheet you should also be able to work as you would any other spreadsheet.  It all depends on what you want to do with the information and where it will end ultimately.

You could also look at tying the data into [dundas charts web parts](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/SharePoint/index.aspx)